# Equivalent Sequential Definitions of Continuity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, continuity

Continuity is often defined as follows:

> $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is continuous if $f\left(x_n\right)\to f\left(x\right)$ for every $\left\{x_n\right\}\subseteq\mathbb R$ such that $x_n\to x$.

I saw an author define it as follows:

> $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is continuous if $\left\{f\left(x_n\right)\right\}$ converges for every convergent $\left\{x_n\right\}\subseteq\mathbb R$.

Are these definitions equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume the second one, we can prove the first one. For a convergent $\{x_{n}\}$, say, $x_{n}\rightarrow x$, let $y_{n}=x$, and $z_{2n}=x_{n}$, $z_{2n+1}=y_{n}=x$, then $z_{n}\rightarrow x$ and by the assumption then $f(z_{n})\rightarrow L$, so $f(z_{2n+1})\rightarrow L$, but $f(z_{2n+1})=f(x)$, so $L=f(x)$. On the other hand, we also have $f(z_{2n})=f(x_{n})\rightarrow L=f(x)$.